# Read large file in chunks in C; how to malloc?

Tags: c, file, hash, malloc

I am trying to read a large data file (44GB - 63GB)

My logic behind what I am doing is allocate memory for 1GB, read that one GB at a time, split it into 1MB at a time and do some generic hash with that 1MB (while taking some performance test in between)

Here is what I have so far:

Any ideas on how I can test this before I go any further? As far as know whether or not my program is dumping the allocated memory of 1GB and then incrementing until I have finally reached the end of the file

I understand I have a lot of work to do still, but so far I am stuck on the idea of how do I increment the file allocation of memory and continue to free that space until the file is read and completed with performance testing

I would like to only calculate how much time the hashing takes within the whole file, I don't want to spend time calculating how much time it takes to read in the file, only interested in how long it takes to perform the hashing within the file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//#define BUFFERSIZEGB 1024*1024*1024 // how many bytes in one gb
//#define BIFFERSIZEMB 1024*1024 // how many bytes in one mb 

int main()
{
    struct stat fileSize;
    char *buffGB, *hashString;

    FILE *fp;
    clock_t elapsed;
    char fname[40];

    printf("Enter name of file:");
    fgets(fname, 40, stdin);
    while (fname[strlen(fname) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname[strlen(fname) -1] = '\0';
    }

    // handle file, open file, and read in binary form
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }

    stat(fname, &fileSize);
    size_t size = fileSize.st_size;
    printf("Size of file: %zd\n", size);

    // allocate one gbs worth of memory (buffersize is in bytes)
    buffGB = malloc(sizeof(*buffGB)*1024*1024*1024); // allocate memory for one gb

    hashString = malloc(sizeof(*hashString)*1024*1024);

    // read the file again one gb at a time? So that I can some cool stuff for testing
    while (fread(buffGB, sizeof(*buffGB), (1024*1024*1024)), fp) == (1024*1024*1024)) 
    {
        elapsed = clock(); // get starting time

        // now read in 1MB at a time (1024*1024 bytes) // use fgets
        if (fgets(hashString, (1024*1024), fp) != NULL) // or pointer to the 1GB?
        {
            puts(hashString);

            // do some generic hash
            // hash that "hashString"
        }

        elapsed = clock() - elapsed; // sum up the time until it's finished with the loop
    }

    // flush the memory and start over again to read the next gb
    // increment by as many times needed until the large gb file has been read?
    free(buffGB);
    free(hashString);

    fclose (fp); // close files

    printf("Hashing took %.2f seconds.\n", (float)elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: fgets is reading further into the file. Not re-reading what you already parked in buffGB. fgets stops "reading" when it its a '\n' character, so you are not reading one MB unless the newline characters are exactly one MB apart.

Comment: Hmm ok, would you suggest I read in the chunk of the file using another while loop with fread?

Comment: Why do you want to read 1GB at a time? If you're only processing 1MB chunks at a time and processing of each chunk is independent, you will not gain any performance by reading more. At best performance will be the same, and more likely you'll hurt performance by storing two copies of all your data (one in the kernel's disk-backed filesystem cache, one in your process's anonymous memory).

Comment: @R.. You're right, I just noticed that; I just thought that 1GB is the highest memory you can allocate for certain systems, and I just wanted to allocate 1GB of memory to be safe

Comment: But actually, I am thinking about using fseek and increment by 1GB at a time and then read in 1MB at a time to hash that 1MB and calculate it's performance

Comment: You don't need to use `fseek`... after one `fread` you'll already be positioned to read the next part of the file.  Lose the `fgets`.  Read a megabyte if you like (performance improvements might become insignificant earlier though - maybe after 32-128kb), then hash it.  As is, elapsed is overwritten every time through the `while` loop, so you're only timing the last iteration.  Re only timing the hashing - just do a version that say treats the input as a series of integers and adds them together, then see how much slower your hash is than that - I/O times will pretty much cancel out.